# JPA returning org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException

Tags: hibernate, exception, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate, database-deadlocks

I have found one scenario on Spring scheduler job. as while doing batch insert and then doing batch update, it is returning **"DeadlockLoserDataAccessException"** exception. this scenario occurs around one every 4 to 5 month.

code : `getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate("Update Query");`

Can you suggest, how I can handle/fix this.

Comment: Do you know which query wins the deadlock? Which database are you using?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö, I am using MYSQL InnoDB and see here first we are insert records in the table named cust_details.

After the insert, we are doing update in table cust_primary_details using batchUpdate.

Currently I only know that this batchUpdate is receiving "DeadlockLoserDataAccessException" exception.

Comment: Not an answer, but https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html describes how to get more info of why a deadlock occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you give basically no information, what you are doing we can only give general recommendations.

1. Consult your database documentation to learn how to debug dead locks, especially how to learn which objects are getting locked and by what statements. Use this to learn what parts of your application are deadlocking.
2. To avoid deadlocks typical strategy is to always obtain locks in the same order. So if you need to access and lock two tables `A` and `B` make sure you always lock `A` first and then `B`. If you don't do this and mix the two, one session might first lock `A` while another session locks `B` resulting in both waiting for the other to release their lock, which will never happen.